# Unable to install docker compose for docker images

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

The docker compose part of the code in the foll. docker file is throwing an error, it is not letting me install docker using the foll. command

```
#Install Docker CLI
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh \
    && curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:sid-slim

# Avoid warnings by switching to noninteractive
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive


#Versions
ENV HELM_VERSION=v3.10.0
ENV KUBECTL_VERSION=v1.20.9
ENV MAVEN_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/cicd/assets/truststore.jks"
ENV TERRAFORM_VERSION=1.2.0
ENV GOLANG_VERSION=1.18.6
ENV TERRAGRUNT_VERSION=v0.38.7
 
RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip

RUN apt-get install zip unzip
#Copy python requirements file
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/pip-tmp/
 
# Makes the Ansible directories
RUN mkdir /etc/ansible /ansible
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh



# Configure apt and install python packages
RUN apt-get update -y -q \
    && apt-get upgrade -y -q \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils dialog 2>&1 \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
    && apt-get -y install ca-certificates software-properties-common build-essential curl git gettext-base maven sshpass krb5-user \
    && pip --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir install -r /tmp/pip-tmp/requirements.txt \
    && apt-get -y install jq \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pip-tmp 
 
#Install helm
RUN wget https://get.helm.sh/helm-${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz \
&& tar -zxvf helm-${HELM_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz \
&& mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm
 
#Install kubectl
RUN curl --silent https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${KUBECTL_VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl --output /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
&& chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl
 
#Install Docker CLI
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh \
    && curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
 
#Install AWS CLI
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" \
&& unzip awscliv2.zip \
&& ./aws/install
```

Error

```
linux-amd64/
linux-amd64/helm
linux-amd64/LICENSE
linux-amd64/README.md
Removing intermediate container 5e9e7dfad8e7
 ---> f973469c13ee
Step 16/33 : RUN curl --silent https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${KUBECTL_VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl --output /usr/local/bin/kubectl && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl
 ---> Running in 291c7de9fa77
Removing intermediate container 291c7de9fa77
 ---> 189d6f646e42
Step 17/33 : RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh     && curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose     && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
 ---> Running in e70582db8ec2
# Executing docker install script, commit: 4f282167c425347a931ccfd95cc91fab041d414f
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
+ sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl >/dev/null
+ sh -c mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings && chmod -R 0755 /etc/apt/keyrings
+ sh -c curl -fsSL "https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg" | gpg --dearmor --yes -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
+ sh -c chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
+ sh -c echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bookworm stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
+ sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bookworm Release' does not have a Release file.
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh     && curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose     && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 100

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 100
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 5da3c5d6-ee0c-4b70-abfd-25cd00202113 completed with status "FAILURE"
```

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] that demonstrates this problem?  Do you need to install the half-dozen other tools and language runtimes, for example, or can you [edit] the question to remove these from the Dockerfile?  Why use the unstable version of Debian, particularly in a container environment?

Answer (score 0):

`debian:sid-slim` refers to `bookworm`, see next:

```
$ docker run --rm -it debian:sid-slim cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid \n \l
```

From the script of `https://get.docker.com/`, you could see next:

```
case "$dist_version" in
    11)
        dist_version="bullseye"
    ;;
    10)
        dist_version="buster"
    ;;
    9)
        dist_version="stretch"
    ;;
    8)
        dist_version="jessie"
    ;;
esac
```

Above means that convenient script haven't supported the next unstable debian release.

As a result, you may could try to [install a docker cli from its prebuilt binaries](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/), next is the exact link for the dockercli binary: https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/